# Differentiable Equations

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=|x|^p$. Find all positive numbers $p$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.
I know that to show that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ I begin with
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{|x|^p}{x}$$. But I do not know where to go from here

Comment: Perhaps we mean as $x\to 0^+$? How are we to interpret $x^{3/2}$ is $x$ is negative?

Comment: Or maybe $p$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is differentiable at zero if and only if

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

exists. We can simplify this quotient as

$$x^{p - 1}$$

if $x > 0$ and

$$\frac{|x|^p}{x} = \frac{|x|^p}{-|x|} = -|x|^{p - 1} $$

if $x < 0$.

Now consider some cases:

- If $p > 1$, the left and right limits are zero, and the function is differentiable with derivative zero.
- If $p = 1$, the left limit is $-1$, while the right limit is $1$.
- If $p < 1$, the right handed limit is $\infty$, so the function fails to have a derivative.